# Updating table data in rails using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have only one view index.html.erb which displays all employee names and all the details in the database. I have a search form wherein the search results should be updated in the table tbody with id "content". my index.html.erb renders fine the first time.
Here is my index.html.erb

```
//my view index.html.erb
<%= form_for :query, :url => { :controller => "home", :action => "show" }, :html =>{:id => "search_form"} do |f|%>
    <div>
        <p>Enter the search keywords:</p>
        <input type="text" id="query_search_key" name="query[search_key]"/>

        <%= f.submit "Search" %>
        <p>Raised By : <select style="width:300px" id="query_raised_by" name="query[raised_by]">
        <option value="-1" selected>Select member</option>
        <% @m_n.each do |m_n| %>
        <option value="<%= m_n.full_name %>"><%= m_n.full_name %></option>
        <% end %>
        </select>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div>
<table id="table" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Sr Number</th><th>Raised By</th><th>Title</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="content">
        <% if @query%>      
            <% @query.each do |query| %>
                <tr><td><%= query.sr_number %></td><td><%= query.from %></td><td><%= query.title %></td></tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

//ajax call handler in index.html.erb
$("#search_form").submit(function(){
    var dataSet = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: dataSet,
        success: function(data){
        //update the contents of tbody with id content
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here is my controller

```
//my controller
class HomeController <  ActionController::Base
  def index

    @m_n = (db query getting member names)
    #displaying al records
    @query = (db query)
  end

  def show
    #displaying filtered results
    @query = (db query)
    flash[:notice] = "success: "+ no_of_results + " were found"
    render :partial => 'search'

  end
end
```

From show action I want to update only the table tbody with id "content" in index.html.erb using @query object.

Comment: how do you want to update tbody with id "content" from show page,do you want to click on any button or when show page action is triggred? can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: when I press search button after entering the search key, the control goes to show action. From there I want to update the table with filtered results using @query object.

Comment: @SahilGrover ANd how will i update the table then??

Comment: hello @FredoCorleone remember Winter is coming..tell Michael Corleone too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to write some partial and add the partial data to tbody

for example:

**controller:**

```
def show
    #displaying filtered results
    @query = (db query)
    #pass @query to index.html.erb and update only the tbody with id=content which takes @query
    render :partial => 'show_partial'

  end
```

**_show_partial.html.erb:**

```
<% if @query%>      
      <% @query.each do |query| %>
          <tr><td><%= query.sr_number %></td><td><%= query.from %></td><td><%= query.title %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and then

```
//ajax call handler in index.html.erb
$("#search_form").submit(function(){
    var dataSet = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: dataSet,
        success: function(data){
              $('#content').html(data)
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I think it may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks a million anusha.. I was struggling for 2 days. I'll upvote.Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Fredo Corleone: With Pleasure Fredo.

Comment: Hey, I want to send a flash[:notice] from controller to view and add it in the div with id "content". I have updated my controller. Could you help plz. I am directly accessing it in the success function as: $("#content").html("<%= flash[:notice] %>"). but it renders only once and the notice doesnt get updated on next ajax call.

Comment: @FredoCorleone: Specify the flash[:notice] in controller and add that in _show_partial.html.erb

Comment: Thanks anusha. Another headache and another perfect answer. Thanks a million

Comment: @FredoCorleone: My Pleasure,Happy to hear that it was helped you.